# How do I print a string output from another string (clear example)

Tags: python, string

i'm trying to make a program for battleships but i'm having an issue with the following program (simplified version)

```
import random
A = "the one"
B = "who"
C = "lost"
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']
D = (random.choice(letters))
print(str(D))
```

It only outputs A B or C
but I want it to output the strings content not the name of the string
eg I want it to print 'the one' 'who' or 'lost' instead of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes so you create a list holding string variables instead of a list holding strings.

```
In [5]: letters = [A, B, C]

In [6]: random.choice(letters)
Out[6]: 'lost'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use variables then, not strings.

```
letters = [A, B, C]
```

When you enclose variable names with quotes, it creates, well, strings.